# Video embed to social media site via oembed not working correctly (twitter, slack, facebook)

Tags: header, next.js, seo, oembed, video-embedding

I've built an application on next.js. For that I'm injecting custom meta tags into the head of page. Following is the content i'm injecting into the Head of document.

```
<title>{`${recordingData.title} - VUMU`}</title>

<meta name="description" content="Check out a video I made via VUMU" />

/* SEO */
<meta property="og:site_name" content="VUMU.IO" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content={`${config.WEB_URL}share/${query.pid}`} />
<meta property="og:title" content={`${recordingData.title} - VUMU`} key="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Check out a video I made via VUMU" />
<meta property="og:image" content={recordingData.thumbnailUrl} />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="720" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />



/* OEMBED links discovery */
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://2rstwutqz5.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/get-recording-oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.vumu.io%2Fshare%2F60d81714d4324bb2b7a595ab&amp;format=json" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://2rstwutqz5.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/get-recording-oembed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstage.vumu.io%2Fshare%2F60d81714d4324bb2b7a595ab&amp;format=xml" />


/* Other tags */
```

Plus following is the link contaings these tags. https://stage.vumu.io/share/60d81714d4324bb2b7a595ab?src=ext

Now the problem is that when i share the link url on actual social media platform it doesn't load up the embeded iframe.

Comment: Note: the <meta> and <link> tags do not use and do not need or require a closing slash on any tag and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Khizer Ali, were you able to figure out a solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @Survy nope ...